# Disable Button HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a submit form for a URL and I want it to have specific behavior which I am not able to achieve so far.  Initially I want the button to be enabled.  After someone enters a URL and hits the "submit" button, I want to call my checkURL() function.  If the function returns true, I want the button to become disabled and I want to then open remote_file.php.  If it returns false, I want the button to be enabled and make them try another URL.

```
<form name=URLSubmitForm
    action="remote_file.php" 
    method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="524288000">
    <input type="text" name="name" size="50">
    <input type="submit" 
        onchange="this.disabled=false"
        onclick="this.disabled=true; checkURL();"
        value="submit">
</form>
```

Edit:  It looks like I was just putting the onchange in the wrong place.  I ended up doing this to fix reenabling the button

`<input type="text" onchange="submit.disabled=false" name="name" size="50">`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose that you attach the event handling code to the form's **onsubmit** event, not the button event(s).  What you're trying to control is whether or not the form is posted.  The button being disabled while your validation logic runs is a secondary goal.

Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkURL(){
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    submitButton.disabled=true;

    /* implement your validation logic here
    if( url is invalid ){
        submitButton.disabled=false;
        return false;
    }
    */

    // everything is valid, allow form to submit
    return true;
}
</script>

<form name="URLSubmitForm" action="remote_file.php" onsubmit="return checkURL();" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="524288000">
        <input type="text" name="name" size="50">
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: returning false from the onclick of a submit button is a common validation pattern

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" 
    onclick="if (checkURL()) { this.disabled='disabled'; return true; } else { return false; }"
    value="submit">
```

Comment: According to the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/disabled) the `disabled` property type is `boolean`

Comment: this is good, except it does not reactivate the button if the text is changed in the box

Comment: it would never have been disabled, because if checkurl returned the form would submit and you get a clean start

Comment: @The Scrum Meister.. its defined as a boolean attribute, but the value is inconsequential, and IE prefers disabled=disabled when setting dynamically (why refer to mozilla docs? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1)

Comment: but if the cheekURL() function returned false then the button is disabled and it can't be reenabled unless I reload the page.  I edited my answer to solve that problem; however, It still won't preform the action of loading remote_file.php

Comment: wrong.. returning false just cancels the propagation of the click event stopping the form to submiting

Comment: actually, I take that back.  you are right, the button is not disabled if checkURL() does not return true.  The real problem is that it is not preforming the action.

Comment: @Corey let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1525/discussion-between-happytime-harry-and-corey)

Comment: @happytime-harry The link you posted is regarding the `disabled` **attribute**, the the **property** of the `Element`. The correct way to set the attribute is `disabled="disabled"`, however when setting the property from javascript, the correct way is `this.disabled = true`.

Answer (score 0):

How about in the form's onsubmit event:

```
<form onsubmit="(function(){
    if(checkURL()){
        this.elements['submit'].disabled = 'disabled';
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
})()">
```

Since you haven't given any ajax code, the form will still be submitted normally and when the page is reloaded the button will be enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

onclick="checkURL(this);"

```
function checkURL(arg){
  this.disabled=true;
  if(<something>) this.disabled=false;
}
```